# Magento 2: Hide Add to cart button in all products

Tags: product, magento2.3, addtocart, custom-attributes

I created a custom attribute for hiding add to card button, it is working only for simple product.
I want Hide to add to cart button for all product.

Create product attribute for `hide_add_to_cart` and placed below code in

> addtocart.phtml

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->getData('hide_add_to_cart')) :?>
    <div class="box-tocart">
        <div class="fieldset">
           <div class="actions disablebtn">
                <button type="submit"

                        class="action primary tocart"
                        id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                         <?php //echo $_product->getData('hide_add_to_cart'); ?>
                </button>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>


    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="box-tocart">
        <div class="fieldset">
            <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="number"
                           name="qty"
                           id="qty"
                           value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                           title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                           />
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit"
                        title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                        class="action primary tocart"
                        id="product-addtocart-button">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
                </button>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                    "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <?php else : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
            }
        }
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what code, you have tried..

Comment: @AmitBera see updated my question

Answer (score 0):

> **Hide Add To Cart Button**

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="hidecartbutton" type="Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin\Hidecartbutton" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin**

**Hidecartbutton.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Vendorename\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Hidecartbutton
{
    public function afterIsSaleable(Product $product, $isSaleable)
    {
        // Add your logic here
        return false;
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***